# Click the non-functioning element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".select-lang-navbar-in").click(function(){
    $("nav div.navbar div.right a.lang .fa-angle-down").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
    $("nav div.navbar div.right div.lang").fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).addClass("select-lang-navbar-out");
    $(this).removeClass("select-lang-navbar-in");
})

$(".select-lang-navbar-out").click(function(){
    alert('okok');
})
```

I have an element with class select-lang-navbar-in and then when the class is clicked it will change the class to select-lang-navbar-out
but when the class select-lang-navbar-out is clicked it doesn't appear alert js

Answer (score 0):

This is because,class 'select-lang-navbar-out' was not present during event binding.
I think you should try:

```
$('.select-lang-navbar-out').on('click',function(){
    alert('okok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the way to define that event to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".select-lang-navbar-out", function () { ... });
```

```js
$(".select-lang-navbar-in").click(function(){
    $("nav div.navbar div.right a.lang .fa-angle-down").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
    $("nav div.navbar div.right div.lang").fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).addClass("select-lang-navbar-out").text("select-lang-navbar-out");
    $(this).removeClass("select-lang-navbar-in");
})

$(document).on("click",".select-lang-navbar-out", function(){
    alert('okok');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="select-lang-navbar-in">select-lang-navbar-in</button>
```

Because when you write:

```
$(".select-lang-navbar-out").click(function(){...});
```

this event will be added to all of the *existing* elements which already have the class `select-lang-navbar-out`.